# wine takes eternity to start in a Node subprocess

Tags: node.js, wine

When i take my console i get (as the most trivial thing i can invent to execute in Wine)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-113:~$ time wine cmd /C echo hello
hello

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.000s
```

which is about as expected, but when i do same from Node subprocess, it takes 4000-5000ms!

`var wine=cp.spawn('wine',['cmd', '/C', 'echo','hello'])`

i suspect this is because the environment is somehow different for that child process and my command line. what can be the fix?

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? it runs fine for me with some simple things like this example of yours, but if i try to run any lightweight program it just hangs in there forever, and consuming a considerable amount of cpu and ram.